# Git command not working in jenkins pipeline - but when i run it locally it works

Tags: git, jenkins

The script I am running in jenkins contains at some point this command:

```
npm update fhir-types --force
```

the outcome is:

> C:\Sources\iw-next\iw.next-ui>npm update fhir-types --force  npm WARN
>   using --force I sure hope you know what you are doing. npm ERR! code
>   128 npm ERR! Command failed: C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.EXE clone
>   --depth=1 -q -b dev https://bitbucket.org/asd/fhir-types.git C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_cacache\tmp\git-clone-1b2dca91
>   --config core.longpaths=true npm ERR! warning: templates not found C:\Windows\TEMP\pacote-git-template-tmp\git-clone-fd08367f npm ERR!
>   remote: Invalid username or password. If you log in via a third party
>   service you must ensure you have an account password set in your
>   account profile. npm ERR! fatal: Authentication failed for
>   'https://bitbucket.org/asd/fhir-types.git/' npm ERR!
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR!
>   C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2017-11-21T07_55_14_306Z-debug.log

When i run this locally it works - is there anyway to change the user and pw for git in the command line before i run this update?

Comment: `fatal: Authentication failed`, it seems the user that runs `npm update` in the Jenkins job does not have the right to access the remote repository.

Comment: the use configured in jenkins to connect to that slave node is the same user I use when i connect manually using RDC - when i connect manually it works - when i run from jenkins it does not - do you know of a way in which i can configure the user manually using the command line before the npm update?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be a few things.  Sometimes Jenkins fails to run `npm update/install` because the file system does not have the correct permissions.  To fix this, run this command on the file system.

```
chmod -R 777 /path/to/jenkins
```

From experience, I've found that issues arising with npm on Jenkins sometimes are due to improper Git configuration.  There are a couple of npm configuration settings that can be tried as well.  I recommend running the rest of the commands from a custom shell inside your Jenkins job.

For starters make sure your Git username and email are set.  Then disable SSL.  It's not the most secure to disable this feature and some consider it a hack, but it works in a lot of cases.

```
git config --global user.name "BobDole"
git config --global user.name "bob.dole@cheescakefactory.org"
git config --global http.sslVerify false
```

It looks like you are using a private Bitbucket repository to hold your npm package.  NPM packages that aren't published to the public npm repository are a little finicky with Jenkins.  You may have to try out some of the npm config settings yourself to see what works: https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/config

My first recommendation is to try and set the registry explicitly to the public npm registry.  This has worked for me with Jenkins in the past.

```
npm config set registry https://registry.npmjs.org/
```

Comment: Hi will try above suggestions and get back to you - Thanks!

Comment: did use the global user name:
git config --global user.name "BobDole"
git config --global user.name "bob.dole@cheescakefactory.org"
git config --global http.sslVerify false

seemed to work after using these